# reset transition when hover out

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, reset

I would like to have the move.down function to reset when i hover off the div.
right now it doesnt resets, but just moves back up again.
any help on this subject would be much appriciated.

See code:

CSS

```
#box_1{
   border-radius:12px;
   display: block;
   position: relative !important;
   width: 204px;
   height: 203px;
   background:url(http://biready.visseninfinland.nl/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/input1.png);
   background-size:204px 203px;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#box_1 .hoverImg {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0; 
   top: 0;
   width: 204px;
   height: 203px;
   display: none;
}

#box_1:hover .hoverImg {
   display: block;
   width: 204px;
   height: 203px;
}

#axis1:hover .move-down {
   transform: translate(0,100px);
   -webkit-transform: translate(0,100px);
   -o-transform: translate(0,100px);
   -moz-transform: translate(0,100px);
}

.object1 {
   position: absolute;
   transition: all 5s ease-in;
   -webkit-transition: all 5s ease-in-out; /** Chrome & Safari **/
   -moz-transition: all 5s ease-in-out; /** Firefox **/
   -o-transition: all 5s ease-in-out; /** Opera **/
}

.object1 {
   position: absolute !important;
}
.line1 {
   top: 8%;
   left: 5%;
   width: 180px;
   height: 15px;
}

#box_1:hover .move-down {
   transform: translate(0,150px);
   -webkit-transform: translate(0,150px);
   -o-transform: translate(0,150px);
   -moz-transform: translate(0,150px);
```

}

HTML

```
<div id="box_1">
<div id="axis1"><img class="object1 line1 move-down" src="http://biready.visseninfinland.nl/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/balkje1.gif"/></div>
<div class="hoverImg"><img src="http://biready.visseninfinland.nl/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/input2-80.png" width="204" height="203" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/38m6u/

Looking forward to a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transition should take place when hovering over `#box_1` instead:

Remove the transition from `.object1` and add it to the selector `#box_1:hover .move-down`

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gy32D/)

```
#box_1:hover .move-down {
    transform: translate(0, 150px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 150px);
    -o-transform: translate(0, 150px);
    -moz-transform: translate(0, 150px);
    transition: all 5s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: @ZachSaucier It works for me on Chrome - Pretty sure the OP is referring to the line that is translated down the element on `hover`. It's barely visible, but it is working.

Comment: this did the trick for me, will this also work if i have more then one  object in a single div. like .object1, .object2, and .object3?

Comment: @LaurensHoogland Yea, it should if you're using a class. In this instance `.move-down`.